# Remove buttons created in for loop python tkinter

Tags: python, function, loops, tkinter

I want that when I go to secondpage and back to the mainpage it removes the buttons created in the `mainloop`. So when I open the second page again, it needs to make the buttons again. with the updated list

Now it shows the buttons 2 times. I know to not add it into a function it will render just 1 time but the point is it will be removed when it is in a function and it need to remaked every time I open the mainpage. So that I can edit for example the list when the application is open and it will be rendered again.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

items = ['ijs', 'water', 'lolly', 'laptop']

root = Tk()

def buttonmaker():
    for x in items:
        button = Button(master=secondpage, text=x ).pack()

def mainpagetosecondpage():
    mainpage.pack_forget()
    buttonmaker()
    secondpage.pack()

def secondpagetomainpage():
    secondpage.pack_forget()
    mainpage.pack()



#mainpage
mainpage = Frame(master=root)
main_to_second_button = Button(master=mainpage, text='secondpage', command=mainpagetosecondpage).pack()

#scondpage
secondpage = Frame(master=root)
Second_to_main_button = Button(master=secondpage, text='mainpage', command=secondpagetomainpage).pack()

mainpage.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If something is unclear, please ask

Answer (score 1):

You need to call buttonmaker only once, during the setup of the second frame:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def buttonmaker():
    items = ['ijs', 'water', 'lolly', 'laptop']
    for x in items:
        button = Button(master=secondpage, text=x )
        button.pack()

def mainpagetosecondpage():
    mainpage.pack_forget()
    secondpage.pack()

def secondpagetomainpage():
    secondpage.pack_forget()
    mainpage.pack()

#mainpage
mainpage = Frame(master=root)
main_to_second_button = Button(master=mainpage, text='secondpage', command=mainpagetosecondpage)
main_to_second_button.pack()

#scondpage
secondpage = Frame(master=root)
Second_to_main_button = Button(master=secondpage, text='mainpage', command=secondpagetomainpage)
Second_to_main_button.pack()
buttonmaker()

mainpage.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Also, you need to avoid putting the layout on the same line as the initialization. Code like `variable = Widget(args).pack()` will lead to bugs. Use 2 lines like I did above.

Comment: I think i asked my question wrong. But let say i want to edit the list items and when i edit the list it renders also the new item. I know this is a bad example but that is it does the function when i open the page so when i did some edits to the list it is added when i press the button to go to the new frame!

Comment: @RikdenHartog I don't understand. You want to edit the button text? Then you need to make a list of button objects and call `btn.config(text=new_text)` for each one. Make a better example and put it in a new post.